# DELETE request works from insomnia/postman but not from the frontend

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, insomnia

DELETE request give 204 response code from Insomnia/Postman, But from the frontend it gives error for Delete request.
Please find my **Service** code below :

```
public bool Dissociate(string envCode, string serialNumber, string gatewayType)
        {
            envCode.ThrowIfNull();
            serialNumber.ThrowIfNull();
            gatewayType.ThrowIfNull();

            if (!IsAssociated(envCode, serialNumber, gatewayType))
            {
                _logService.Warn($"DspService - Dissociate - {gatewayType} {serialNumber} not associated to DSP tenant on environment {envCode}");
                return false;
            }

            EnvironmentSettings dspEnvSettings = GetEnvironmentSettings(envCode);
            string baseUri = DspHelper.GetBaseUriByAction(dspEnvSettings, DspActionType.Dissociate);
            string dspDeviceId = DspHelper.BuildDeviceId(serialNumber, gatewayType, true);

            string uri = $"{baseUri}/registry/devices/{dspDeviceId}/claim";
            var body = new
            {
                Claimable = true
            };
            try
            {
                var authToken = GetAuthorizationHeader(dspEnvSettings, DspActionType.Dissociate);
                RunDspCommand<bool>(dspEnvSettings, uri, authToken, body, HttpMethod.Put, DspActionType.Dissociate);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logService.ErrorException(e, $"DspService - Dissociate - Error dissociating {gatewayType} {serialNumber} on environment {envCode}. {uri}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Please find my insomnia response: 
[image]

[image]

**CONTROLLER :**

```
[AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
        [Route("dissociate")]
        public bool Dissociate([FromUri] string gatewayType, [FromUri] string gatewaySerial)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gatewaySerial) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(gatewayType))
            {
                this.BadRequestResponse();
            }

            var connectedUser = this.permissionService.GetConnectedUser();
            this.permissionService.CheckRolePermission(connectedUser.Role, PermissionConstant.DissociateComX);

            bool hasSucceeded = this.dspService.Dissociate(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, gatewaySerial, gatewayType);
            if (hasSucceeded)
            {
                this.applicationDataAccess.LogAction(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, connectedUser.Email, LogActionConstants.Action.DissociateComX, string.Format(LogActionConstants.Message.DissociateComX, gatewayType, gatewaySerial));
            }
            else
            {
                this.BadRequestResponse("cannot deprovioned comx");
            }

            return hasSucceeded;
        }
```

It gives the exception in the Service Code

```
                RunDspCommand<bool>(dspEnvSettings, uri, authToken, body, HttpMethod.Put, DspActionType.Dissociate);
```

Below is my **front end** code. 
controller.ts

```
dissociateGateway() {
      if (!this.isDspGateway || this.isLoadingDspState || this.isDissociating
        || this.gateway.FirmwareUpgradeWorkflow || this.gateway.DeleteGatewayWorkflow
        || !this.isAssociated()) {
        return;
      }

      this.modalService.confirm(
        `The ${this.gateway.Type} ${this.gateway.SerialNumber} will be dissociated from its DSP tenant ${this
          .dspGatewayState.Tenant}.`,
        'Are you sure you want to dissociate the gateway from DSP tenant?')
        .then(() => {
          this.isDissociating = true;
          this.dspService.dissociate(this.gateway.Type, this.getDeviceId())
            .then(() => this.getDspGatewayState())
            .catch((e) => {
              if (e) {
                this.modalService.error('Error dissociating the gateway. Please retry later');
              }
            })
            .finally(() => this.isDissociating = false);
        });
    }
```

service.ts

```
        dissociate(gatewayType: string, gatewaySerial: string): ng.IPromise<boolean> {
            var uri = this.ROUTES.dissociate
                .replace('{:gatewayType}', gatewayType.toString())
                .replace('{:gatewaySerial}', gatewaySerial);

            return this.restService
                .delete(uri, null)
                .then((response: any) => {
                    return response;
                })
                .catch((response: any) => {
                    return this.$q.reject(response);
                });
        }
```

Path :

```
dissociate: '/dsp/dissociate?gatewaytype={:gatewayType}&gatewaySerial={:gatewaySerial}',
```

If you need more information please comment below.
Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you getting error related to CORS?

Comment: @Chetan : I get this error { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }, But in Insomnia/Postman i get 204 response.

Comment: Can  you share the frontend code too?

Comment: Yes Sure. I will update my question with front end code.

Comment: are you using the correct http verb for the `delete` when sending the API request from the Front end?

Comment: @thanzeel : Yes, Used Http Verb DELETE.

Comment: @Philip ,are you using asp.net core or the as.net framework?

Comment: @thanzeel : I am using .net framework.

Comment: have the inspected the network tab of the browser when sending the http request from the browser to the API? are the URLs in the network tab and postman/insomnia the same? are there any addition headers or data being passed?

Comment: @thanzeel : Yes, In the Network Tab GatewayType and GatewaySerialNumber is passed. Where in Insomnia it is not passed.

Comment: @Philip, is the gatewaytype and gatewayserialnumber needed by the API?

Comment: @thanzeel : Yes. We need to pass this parameters.

Comment: are they passes as part of the query string or route url? try hitting the API without those 2 parameters if its working